# Error in manipulating sting with "\" in Lua

Tags: lua

```
local filepath = "c:\\temp\\parentdir"
local dirname = string.match(filepath, "[^\\]+$")
print(dirname)
```

Above code is giving correct output: `parentdir`

Then if I use same code but only single `"\"` as below

```
local filepath = "c:\temp\parentdir"
local dirname = string.match(filepath, "[^\\]+$")
print(dirname)
```

I'm getting this error

```
"lua: main.lua:1: invalid escape sequence near '"c: emp\p'"
```

please help. How we can solve this issue programatically

Comment: The error message tells you that the escape sequence `\p` is invalid.

Comment: ok thanks @ilf
then how we can solve this issue programatically.

Comment: You can use long strings: `[[c:\temp\parentdir]]`. They don't interpret escape sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a issue, becaouse you not provide `c:\temp\parentdir` literally, but `c:{tab}emp{unknown_character}arentdir`. To provide `c:\temp\parentdir` you can use:

1. "c:\\temp\\parentdir"
2. 'c:\\temp\\parentdir'
3. [[c:\temp\parentdir]]

If you read `c:\temp\parentdir` from file or input you not have to add second `\`, because this is only in code escape character. More about [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html).

Second solution is to use `/` instead `\`.